# Create a finite stream with a generator function

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a program to read data from multiple sources, use a tournament tree to merge sort them, pack the data into blocks and output the blocks. I have implemented this as a function, which returns null when no more block is available.

```
DataBlock buildBlock()
```

Now I want to output a stream of blocks, but the only method I have found so far is `Stream.generate` which generates an infinite stream. My stream is of course not infinite. What is a proper way to generate a finite stream from this function?

Comment: You can `limit` it. But that depends on the source of your stream.

Comment: You are right. I do not know the actual amount of data until I can read no more from the source, so I have no idea in advance how many blocks to limit

Comment: You seem to be looking for a [while loop equivalent of streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700006/is-there-java-stream-equivalent-to-while-with-variable-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

If you use at least Java 9, you can apply [`takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) on your stream. If you use the older Java version, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stream of `Optional`'s with `Stream.iterate​(T seed, Predicate<? super T> hasNext, UnaryOperator<T> next)`, stopping on empty. You can then call `.map(Optional::get)` on the stream.

Here's an example of creating a stream that tracks the cumulative sum of a list.

```java
public static Stream<Integer> cumulativeSum(List<Integer> nums) {
    Iterator<Integer> numItr = nums.iterator();
    if (!numItr.hasNext()) {
        return Stream.of();
    }

    return Stream.iterate(
                    Optional.of(numItr.next()),
                    Optional::isPresent,
                    maybeSum -> maybeSum.flatMap(sum ->
                            numItr.hasNext() ? Optional.of(Integer.sum(sum, numItr.next())) : Optional.empty()))
            .map(Optional::get);
}
```

If the input list is `[2, 4, 3]`, then the output stream will be `[2, 6, 9]`.

(Java 8 only has `Stream.iterate​(T seed, UnaryOperator<T> f)`, so you will have to call `.takeWhile(Optional::isPresent)` instead to convert the infinite stream to a finite stream.)